# Is it possible to scrape Metacritic movie pages?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, web-scraping

With this code:

```
public void MetaCriticScrap()
{
    var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.metacritic.com/movie/boyhood");
    var response = http.GetResponse();

    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var wr = new StreamWriter("scrap.txt");
    wr.WriteLine(content);
    wr.Close();

    System.Console.WriteLine(content);
    response.Close();
}
```

It's now allowing me to scrape this page. I don't think it's the actual codes problem as when I put any other URL (google search etc) it scrapes perfectly fine.

Error Message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
```

Full Exception Settings:

```
 System.Net.WebException was unhandled
 HResult=-2146233079
 Message=The remote server returned an error: (429) Unknown.
 Source=System
 StackTrace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at ShouldIWatch.DisplayPage.MetaCriticScrap() in DisplayPage.xaml.cs:line 80
   at ShouldIWatch.DisplayPage..ctor() in DisplayPage.xaml.cs:line 31
   at ShouldIWatch.MainWindow.DannyBrownButton(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 89
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnAccessKey(AccessKeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.AccessKeyManager.ProcessKey(List`1 targets, String key, Boolean existsElsewhere, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Input.AccessKeyManager.ProcessKeyForSender(Object sender, String key, Boolean existsElsewhere, Boolean userInitiated)
   at System.Windows.Input.AccessKeyManager.OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.AccessKeyManager.PostProcessInput(Object sender, ProcessInputEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.RaiseProcessInputEventHandlers(ProcessInputEventHandler postProcessInput, ProcessInputEventArgs processInputEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawKeyboardActions actions, Int32 scanCode, Boolean isExtendedKey, Boolean isSystemKey, Int32 virtualKey)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndKeyboardInputProvider.ProcessKeyAction(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.CriticalTranslateAccelerator(MSG& msg, ModifierKeys modifiers)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessage(Object param)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.OnPreprocessMessageThunk(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.WeakEventPreprocessMessage.OnPreprocessMessage(MSG& msg, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcherThread.RaiseThreadMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at ShouldIWatch.app.Main() in obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
   InnerException:
```

**My final goal is to go on a MetaCritc Page and get the MetaScore and User Rating. Anyway way to do this or do I have to give up? :(**

Thanks for reading. New C# developer.

Comment: Have you looked up what HTTP 429 means? Any chance you're looping this method?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Yeah I see that means "Too Many Requests". But I don't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm doing the exact same thing with other web pages and it gets accepted. So I was thinking that Metacrtic just blocks any scraping and displays a 429 error.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use their [API](https://market.mashape.com/byroredux/metacritic-v2#find-movie) and avoid the scrapping work?

It's much much easier, by using their API you'll get a json response like this, which contains the info you need

```
{
"result": {
"name": "Star Trek Into Darkness",
"score": "72",
"genre": [
  "Action",
  "Adventure",
  "Sci-Fi",
  "Thriller"
],
"thumbnail": "http://static.metacritic.com/images/products/movies/4/c7350d7a54a3301ee5c3d218df59ad45-98.jpg",
"userscore": 7.8,
"summary": "After the crew of the Enterprise find an unstoppable force of terror from within their own organization, Captain Kirk leads a manhunt to a war-zone world to capture a one man weapon of mass destruction.",
"runtime": "132 min",
"director": "J.J. Abrams",
"cast": "Benedict Cumberbatch, Chris Pine, Zachary Quinto, Zoe Saldana",
"rating": "PG-13",
"rlsdate": "2013-05-15",
"url": "http://www.metacritic.com/movie/star-trek-into-darkness"
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this however I'm very new to APIs so I'm unsure what to do. When I click on the Test endpoint button It says I have to pay for subscription? How am I supposed to go about this? And is that code even compatible with C# wpf?

Comment: Believe me scrapping is going to be much much harder. They have a free package. They even have a .net api which makes it easier for you.

Comment: Yeah I want to use this API method but I'm not sure exactly were to start. Can you please link a good guide or provide sample code please?

Comment: Go in the link I posted above, in the right side, select .NET and there is a sample request in there. Read carefully the documenation

Answer (score 1):

I tested the code myself and received the same error. After I manipulated the `UserAgent` to something, they let you download the page.

```
var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.metacritic.com/movie/boyhood");
http.UserAgent = "Mozilla.. Haha, not really.";
try {
    var response = http.GetResponse();

    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
    var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var wr = new StreamWriter("scrap.txt");
    wr.WriteLine(content);
    wr.Close();
    Debug.WriteLine(content);
    response.Close();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    //Get the returned data to see what kind of error occured
    string s = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    Debug.WriteLine(s);
}
```

gives me

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
      xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
            <title>Boyhood Reviews - Metacritic</title>
```

..
But really, you should consider using the API as pointed out by another answer. But this answers your "Why do I get a 429 error".

Comment: Thank you, yeah I will look at the API.